# On App start get location in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Here is the scenario I have.

On App Start for the first time I need the users location, to fetch a list of places closest to them.

If they Allow location access, i then want to use their location to present the list of places to them.

I make a call to update the list in didUpdateLocation, but the list is always empty even after allowing access the first time. When I open the app the second time the location is available and I have the coordinates and can proceed with showing the list which works.

I have also tried running the code to populate the list in theses 2 delegate methods :

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus){ 
  // switch statements then          
  fectchPlacesAndPopulateList()
}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        print("locationManager")
        Utils.creatErrorMessage(title: "aaa", message: "aaaa", vc: self)

        let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as! CLLocation
        let lng = userLocation.coordinate.longitude;
        let lat = userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        let coordinates = "\(lat),\(lng)"
        print("update locations = \(coordinates)")
        fectchPlacesAndPopulateList()
    }

 var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


 if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {


                locationManager.delegate = self
                locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
                locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
}
```

Comment: Is `didUpdateLocations` called?

Comment: @NobodyNada, no  it's not called

Comment: I presume it's called at some point but not after i tap allow. I need to popluate the list the moment i have the location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of `didUpdateLocations` is wrong for Swift 3, note the leading underscore, the (non-optional) type of the manager and the return type

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
```

Comment: three hours of messing around and it came down to an underscore and return type!... Thanks for saving my sanity, lesson learned!